# Можно ли получить класс шаблонного параметра в методе на java

Tags: java, шаблоны

Имеется код-прослойка между двух библиотек

```
    public <T> T load(String assetName)  {
    internalManager.get(rootDirectory + assetName, T.class);
    }
```

Вернее, что-то такое я бы хотел получить, поскольку этот вариант не работает =) Есть ли возможность получить class у параметра T ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, такой возможности нет. Только явно.

```
  public <T> T load(String assetName, Class<T> aClass)  {
   internalManager.get(rootDirectory + assetName, aClass);    
  }
```

Comment: это явление называется [Type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо, не знал :)

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя, параметризованный метод на этапе компиляции все равно должен понимать все возможные комбинации его реализации. Так что единственный способ передать в параметре вызова (как указал AngryBird) или через член класса, типа:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    T t;

    public <T> T load(String asset)
    {
        internalManager.get(rootDirectory + assetName, t.getClass());
        return t;
    }
}
```